# Associative container to handle one element polymorphically

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { val1 = 1;}
    ~A() { }

private:
    int val1;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() { val2 = 1;}
    ~B() { }
    int getVal() {return val2;}

private:
    int val2;
};

class C : public A, public B
{

    int val3;
};

void fun(std::pair<int, B>& p) {
    cout << "B val: " << p.second.getVal() << endl;
}

void fun2(B& b) {
    cout << "B val: " << b.getVal() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    map<int, C> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(1, C()));
    m.insert(make_pair(2, C()));

    //fun(*(m.begin())); // <---- Compilation error
    fun2(m.at(1)); // Works correctly

    return 0;
}
```

Code compiles successfully and works as expected when I make the call to `fun2`. However if I uncomment the line `fun(*(m.begin())` I get the following compilation error:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
a.cpp:48:18: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::pair<int, B>&’ from expression of type ‘std::pair<const int, C>’
  fun(*(m.begin()));
                  ^
a.cpp:33:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void fun(std::pair<int, B>&)’
 void fun(std::pair<int, B>& p) {
```

Is there any way to make the compiler handle the second element of `std::pair` polymorphically?

P.S. Sorry if the title is misleading in any way. Couldn't find a better way of expressing this.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the keys are constant, so `fun()` should accept `std::pair<const int, B>&`. Note that if this works, it will slice the `C` object using `B`'s copy constructor. If you want the objects treated polymorphically, they need to be accessed via a pointer or reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 *(m.begin())
```

evaluates to a nameless temporary object. To bind this to a reference, the reference must be const, so:

```
 void fun(const std::pair<int, B>& p) {
```

and for that function to call getVal(), that must be const too:

```
 int getVal() const {return val2;}
```